# Two background images one starts where the other ends

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and want to achieve something like the below demonstrated outline. An image is shown on top of div, and as the user scrolls vertically, the other image is shown repeatedly.

However, I want to show the repeat.png exactly where the stayontop.png ends vertically. How can I achieve this? I tried different `background-position:center top, center bottom;` variations but no luck.

**EDIT:** Because the height of background image is in `auto` mode (`background-size:100% auto, 100% auto !important;`) Any solution which is based on the static height reference such as `background-position:center 50px;` unfortunately works fine in one div width, but fails when the user resize the div. (Actually when another user visits the site, with a mobile phone which has different resolution.) Is there anyway to set it dynamically?

!-+-+-+-+-+-+-

stayontop.png

!-+-+-+-+-+-+-

repat.png

!-+-+-+-+-+-+-

repat.png

!-+-+-+-+-+-+-

repat.png

!-+-+-+-+-+-+-

.....

```
.hede{
    background: url("css/images/stayontop.png"), url("css/images/repeat.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-y;
    background-position:center top, center bottom;
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
    background-size:100% auto, 100% auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: You can't specify a `top` value for a background which is repeated along the y axis because it will be repeated both upwards and downwards. Both answers right now should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background position property accepts a length value, besides just `top`, `center`, and `bottom`.  So, just specify in pixels where stayontop.png ends:

```css
background-position: center 200px;
```

Set the background position with JavaScript whenever the window is resized:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/rKD8M/

```
onresize = resetBackgrounds;
function resetBackgrounds() {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(".hede");
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var h = els[i].clientWidth * aspectRatio;  // must define aspectRatio
        els[i].style.backgroundPosition = "center top, center " + h + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilly3, it seems the easiest workaround and it works in certain widths, but it fails when the user resize the div. Is there any other way? I also updated the question.

Comment: @noway - I've updated my answer with a JavaScript approach.  My hat goes off to anyone who can come up with pure CSS solution.

Comment: I would advise against using javascript for something as important as the background, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @PeterVR - I'm curious, what would qualify as unimportant?  The background seems quite trivial to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would just need to make sure that the height of the stayontop image is the same as that of the repeated image (or 2x, 3x, 4x the height) and have both aligned to top.

You also need to make sure the browsers going to you site support multiple background images.

For cross-browser compliance you are probably better off using two HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a nice recommendation, however, my stayontop.png is shorter nearly 10 times comparet to repeat.png, therefore, it is not helpfull for my case.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above will probably be the best solution, but just throwing another quick idea in.
http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/8FMB7/1/
I wouldn't use it in exactly this form, but you get the idea, by position the 2 backgrounds top and bottom it will created the desired split.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alexander, it works in certain widths, but it fails when the user resize the div. Is there any other way? I also updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

for browser compatibility i would try something in this order:

```
   .hede{
        background: url("css/images/repeat.png");
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        background-position:center top;
        background-size:100% auto;
        min-height:100%;
        margin-top: 20px; // assumed height of stayontop.png
    }
    .hede:before {
        content: url("css/images/stayontop.png");
        height: 20px; 
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

You might have to tweak the code a bit, but it should be possible...

**edit:**
changing the :before css to this might solve the resizing problem:

```
.hede:before {
  content: url("css/images/stayontop.png");
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: -20px auto 0; 
}
```

not entirely sure, but it's worth a try...

Comment: THanks for the answer, it works in certain widths, but it fails when the user resize the div. Is there any other way? I also updated the question.